# VBA Project, Copy enabled labels and textboxes from a userform to another userform

Tags: excel, vba

I have a VBA project. There are two Userforms. On the first Userform, I chose some of them to be enabled and input a value in the respective text box. Then when I press the Next Button, it should control which Labels are enabled and which respective Text boxes have value so it should copy them (Labels and textboxes with its value) to another Userform and arrange them in a Grid (4 column and 3 Rows). The code works with copying but it doesn't work with positioning the labels and textboxes. Anyone can help me to fix this issue?

P.S. I have asked this question on MrExcel but no one answered so I asked it here.

```
Private Sub TransferDataToClassForm()
    Const MaxPairsPerRow As Integer = 4
    Const LabelWidth As Integer = 190
    Const TextBoxWidth As Integer = 40
    Const ControlHeight As Integer = 22
    Const HorizontalSpacing As Integer = 10
    Const VerticalSpacing As Integer = 25
    Const StartingTop As Integer = 10
    Const StartingLeft As Integer = 10
    Dim currentTop As Integer: currentTop = StartingTop
    Dim currentLeft As Integer: currentLeft = StartingLeft
    Dim pairCounter As Integer: pairCounter = 0

  
    Load Class

    ClearDynamicControls Class.C_Parameters

 
    Dim ctrl As Control
    For Each ctrl In Weight.Controls
        If TypeName(ctrl) = "Label" And ctrl.Enabled Then
          
            Dim newLabel As MSForms.Label
            Set newLabel = Class.C_Parameters.Controls.Add("Forms.Label.1", "DynamicLabel" & ctrl.Name, True)
            newLabel.Caption = ctrl.Caption
            newLabel.top = currentTop
            newLabel.left = currentLeft
            newLabel.width = LabelWidth
            newLabel.height = ControlHeight
          
        ElseIf TypeName(ctrl) = "TextBox" Then
            
            Dim tb As MSForms.TextBox
            Set tb = ctrl
            If tb.Text <> "" Then
              
                Dim newTextBox As MSForms.TextBox
                Set newTextBox = Class.C_Parameters.Controls.Add("Forms.TextBox.1", "DynamicTextBox" & ctrl.Name, True)
                newTextBox.Text = tb.Text
                newTextBox.top = currentTop
                newTextBox.left = currentLeft + LabelWidth + HorizontalSpacing
                newTextBox.width = TextBoxWidth
                newTextBox.height = ControlHeight

              
                pairCounter = pairCounter + 1
                If pairCounter >= MaxPairsPerRow Then
                  
                    currentTop = currentTop + ControlHeight + VerticalSpacing
                    currentLeft = StartingLeft
                    pairCounter = 0
                Else

                    currentLeft = currentLeft + LabelWidth + TextBoxWidth + HorizontalSpacing
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next ctrl


    Class.Show
End Sub

Private Sub ClearDynamicControls(frm As MSForms.Frame)
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = frm.Controls.Count To 1 Step -1
        Dim ctrl As Control
        Set ctrl = frm.Controls(i)
        If left(ctrl.Name, 7) = "Dynamic" Then
            frm.Controls.Remove (ctrl.Name)
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: "it doesn't work with positioning the labels and textboxes" - assuming you mean it doesn't position related labels and textboxes next to each other?  Maybe you need some type of naming convention to allow you to identify the "matched" textbox for any enabled label, so you can copy and position it along with the label?  Eg if the label is named `lblA` then the textbox would be `txtA`.

Comment: If a label is enabled but the associated textbox is blank would you skip them both?

Comment: Labels and textboxes are named accordingly. Label: LBL_Volume and Textboxes: TXT_Volume
If the textbox has no value, it would skip both

Answer (score 0):

Like this (untested but you get the basic approach)

```
Private Sub TransferDataToClassForm()
    
    Const MaxPairsPerRow As Integer = 4
    Const LabelWidth As Integer = 190
    Const TextBoxWidth As Integer = 40
    Const ControlHeight As Integer = 22
    Const HorizontalSpacing As Integer = 10
    Const VerticalSpacing As Integer = 25
    Const StartingTop As Integer = 10
    Const StartingLeft As Integer = 10
    
    Dim currentTop As Integer, currentLeft As Integer, n As Integer
    
    currentTop = StartingTop
    currentLeft = StartingLeft
    n = 0

    Load Class

    ClearDynamicControls Class.C_Parameters

    Dim ctrl As Control, tb As MSForms.TextBox
    For Each ctrl In Weight.Controls
        If TypeName(ctrl) = "Label" And ctrl.Enabled Then
            
            Set tb = Nothing       'clear any previous reference
            On Error Resume Next   'ignore error if not matching control
            Set tb = Weight.Controls(Replace(ctrl.Name, "LBL_", "TXT_"))
            On Error GoTo 0        'stop ignoring errors
            
            If Not tb Is Nothing Then       'got a matching textbox?
                If Len(tb.text) > 0 Then    'textbox has content?
                    
                    'Add the new label and textbox
                    Dim newLabel As MSForms.Label
                    Set newLabel = Class.C_Parameters.Controls.Add( _
                                   "Forms.Label.1", "DynamicLabel" & ctrl.Name, True)
                    newLabel.Caption = ctrl.Caption
                    newLabel.top = currentTop
                    newLabel.Left = currentLeft
                    newLabel.Width = LabelWidth
                    newLabel.Height = ControlHeight
                    
                    Dim newTextBox As MSForms.TextBox
                    Set newTextBox = Class.C_Parameters.Controls.Add( _
                                   "Forms.TextBox.1", "DynamicTextBox" & tb.Name, True)
                    newTextBox.text = tb.text
                    newTextBox.top = currentTop
                    newTextBox.Left = currentLeft + LabelWidth + HorizontalSpacing
                    newTextBox.Width = TextBoxWidth
                    newTextBox.Height = ControlHeight
                    
                    n = n + 1
                    If n Mod MaxPairsPerRow = 0 Then 'end of a row?
                        currentTop = currentTop + ControlHeight + VerticalSpacing
                        currentLeft = StartingLeft
                    Else
                        currentLeft = currentLeft + LabelWidth + TextBoxWidth + HorizontalSpacing
                    End If
                
                End If     'matched textbox not empty
            End If         'have matched textbox
        End If             'is label
    Next ctrl

    Class.Show
End Sub
```